# my setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build error. can you please help me?

Tags: flutter, stream, future, setstate, provider

First of all, I have to say that I have also examined other issues about this error, but could not find a solution.

i get an error like this:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building LoginPage(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery]):
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

This Overlay widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets.  A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was: Overlay-[LabeledGlobalKey<OverlayState>#c8e35]
    state: OverlayState#58ca1(entries: [OverlayEntry#26031(opaque: true; maintainState: false), OverlayEntry#307a6(opaque: false; maintainState: true), OverlayEntry#70b4a(opaque: false; maintainState: false), OverlayEntry#4c25b(opaque: false; maintainState: true)])
The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was: LoginPage
The relevant error-causing widget was
LoginPage
lib\…\screens\landing_page.dart:20
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      Element.markNeedsBuild.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4138
#1      Element.markNeedsBuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4153
#2      State.setState
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:1287
#3      OverlayState.rearrange
package:flutter/…/widgets/overlay.dart:436
#4      NavigatorState._flushHistoryUpdates
package:flutter/…/widgets/navigator.dart:4043
...


════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 4517 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was
LoginPage
lib\…\screens\landing_page.dart:20

E/flutter ( 4507): #5      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)
E/flutter ( 4507): #6      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:152:18)
E/flutter ( 4507): #7      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:704:45)
E/flutter ( 4507): #8      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:733:32)
E/flutter ( 4507): #9      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:539:5)
E/flutter ( 4507): #10     Future._asyncCompleteWithValue.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:577:7)
E/flutter ( 4507): #11     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1354:13)
E/flutter ( 4507): #12     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1258:19)
E/flutter ( 4507): #13     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1162:7)
E/flutter ( 4507): #14     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1202:23)
E/flutter ( 4507): #15     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
E/flutter ( 4507): #16     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
```

my main method is like this:

```
 main(List<String> args) async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(
     MultiProvider(
       providers: [
         ChangeNotifierProvider(create:(_)=> AuthService()),
       ],
       child: MyApp()),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: GoogleFonts.oxanium().fontFamily),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
     initialRoute: "/",
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => LandingPage(),
        'login': (context) => LoginPage(),
        'register': (context) => RegisterPage(),
        'game': (context) => GamePage(),
        'main': (context) => MainPage(),
        'profile': (context) => ProfilePage(),
        'beforeQ': (context) => BeforeQuestionPage(),
        'editProfile': (context) => EditProfilePage(),
        'question': (context) => QuestionPage(),
        'shop': (context) => ShopPage(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

and my landing page is like this:

```
class LandingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final auth = Provider.of<AuthService>(context);
    switch (auth.userState) {
      case UserStates.LoggingIn:
        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
        );

      case UserStates.NotLoggedIn:
        return LoginPage();

      case UserStates.LoggedIn:
        return MainPage();

      default:
        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
        );
    }

    
  }
}
```

as i said, i tried to try the solution suggestions on other issues but it could not solve my problem. That's why I opened this thread. Can someone who knows any solution for my problem give an answer? Thank you from now

Comment: The error is in `LoginPage()` can you post the code for it?

Comment: yes, the error was in LoginPage (). When I redirected to another page, there was no error. Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Future.delayed`

```
Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {

    setState(() {});

});
```

Comment: This is a code smell.  You have just come out of a rebuild... why would you want to rebuild immediately again?  Not going to do well for performance.  Never call setState without indicating *what* changed to deserve the rebuild.